# Match regex at exact offset

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to check if a certain pattern (eg. a double quoted string) matches at an exact position.

**Example**

```
string text = "aaabbb";
Regex regex = new Regex("b+");
// Now match regex at exactly char 3 (offset) of text
```

I'd like to check if `regex` matches at exactly char 3.
I had a look at the `Regex.Match Method (String, Int32)` but it does not behave like I expected.
So I did some tests and some workarounds:

```
public void RegexTest2()
{
    Match m;
    string text = "aaabbb";
    int offset = 3;

    m = new Regex("^a+").Match(text, 0); // lets do a sanity check first
    Assert.AreEqual(true, m.Success);
    Assert.AreEqual("aaa", m.Value);  // works as expected

    m = new Regex("^b+").Match(text, offset);
    Assert.AreEqual(false, m.Success);  // this is quite strange...

    m = new Regex("^.{"+offset+"}(b+)").Match(text); // works, but is not very 'nice'
    Assert.AreEqual(true, m.Success);
    Assert.AreEqual("bbb", m.Groups[1].Value);

    m = new Regex("^b+").Match(text.Substring(offset)); // works too, but 
    Assert.AreEqual(true, m.Success);
    Assert.AreEqual("bbb", m.Value);
}
```

In fact I'm starting to believe that `new Regex("^.", 1).Match(myString)` will *never match anything.*

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I got a working solution (workaround). So my question is all about speed and a nice implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried what the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx) say?

> If you want to restrict a match so
>   that it begins at a particular
>   character position in the string and
>   the regular expression engine does not
>   scan the remainder of the string for a
>   match, anchor the regular expression
>   with a \G (at the left for a
>   left-to-right pattern, or at the right
>   for a right-to-left pattern). This
>   restricts the match so it must start
>   exactly at startat.

i.e. replace the `^` with a `\G`:

```
m = new Regex(@"\\Gb+").Match(text, offset);
Assert.AreEqual(true, m.Success);  // should now work
```

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds, took me too long to confirm `:P`. `\G` is correct here, but I would add a warning about using the same `Regex` object, assuming the OP will not create a new one every time. I'm not quite sure how it would behave, but it may remember the last position, even with the offset. It's worth checking that one. (again, I'm not sure)

Comment: @Kobi - I suspect this may be the case only if you use m.MatchNext(), not if you call Match() again on the same Regex object.

Comment: @CAFxX: It should be `@"\Gb+"` or `"\\Gb+"`.

Comment: I did read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx : `The match must occur at the point where the previous match ended.`which did not convince me to try it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You expect `Match(text, offset)` to **start** evaluate the searched string as if it were starting at the offset. This is not so. `^` will actually evaluate to offset `0`, not `offset`!

So use the [overload of Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09aybcd) that will evaluate `^` to `offset`:

```
m = new Regex("^bbb$").Match(text, offset, text.Length-offset);
```

another option would be to use but it is slower than the one above:

```
m = new Regex("^.{"+offset+"}bbb$").Match(text);
```

or this (the first method is the fastest):

```
m = new Regex(@"\Gbbb$").Match(text, offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a positive lookbehind assertion (`(?<=...)`) to your regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=\A.{3})b+");
```

This ensures that there are exactly three characters (`.{3}`) after the start of the string (`\A`) and before the start of the regex. You can also use `^` instead of `\A`, but since the former can also mean (in some circumstances) "Match at the start of a line", the latter is a bit more explicit.

You might need to compile the regex using `RegexOptions.Singleline` to allow the dot to also match newline characters if that's a requirement.

By the way,

```
m = new Regex("^b+").Match(text, 3);
```

doesn't work because `^` matches at the start of the line, and the position before the first `b` is, of course, not at the start of the line.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, that the offset of '3' is a variable. Wont it decrease performance dramatically if I built a new regex for every call?

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd advocate the use of `Substring` to first get the relevant part of your string and then unleash the fury of regexes on the rest.

Comment: Isn't that slow if the string to be matched on is _very long_?